# Git keeps showing file to be committed

Tags: git

Git keeps telling me that a file needs to be committed:

```
D:\ecs [master +0 ~1 -0]> git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   core/src/main/resources/templates/html/core/ContentStoreView.ftl
#
```

I don't see a change to that file:

```
D:\ecs [master +0 ~1 -0]> git diff core/src/main/resources/templates/html/core/ContentStoreView.ftl
```

I tried committing:

```
git commit -m "commiting you" .
```

I get

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

As well as checking out:

```
D:\ecs [master +0 ~1 -0]> git checkout core/src/main/resources/templates/html/core/ContentStoreView.ftl
```

What's wrong with this file and how can I fix it? (I'm using `git version 1.8.0.msysgit.0` on windows)

UPDATE: The problem disappeared after doing a commit from Netbeans IDE. This is of course not a generic solution and doesn't help me undertand what the problem was.

Comment: What are your newline settings?

Comment: did the git server time sync with your workstation ?

Comment: Have you tried checking what's in the staging area (`git status`), then `git commit -m <message>` [note the lack of period `.`]? The file that's changed isn't in the current directory, and I'm *fairly* sure that `git commit .` will only commit the changes from current directory.

Comment: @simont I did also try with the full path, but . ususally works and does commit thing in subdir.

Answer (score 2):

`git diff --staged` (or `git diff --cached`) will show you the modifications that have been staged but not committed.